# Creating a MySQL Query in one step beside of two

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create an event on my database which will be executed every 6 hours,
Currently I'm doing this daily and it's annoying because sometimes I forget to do it,
I'm doing this on 2 steps

```
Select A.id_ from
timemanagement_Assignment as A
Left join project_Task as T on T.id_ =A.task_id_
Left join project_Phase as P on P.id_ =T. phase_id_
Left join project_Iteration as I on I.id_ =P. iteration_id_
Left join project_Lot as L on L.id_ =I. Lot_id_
Left join project_Project as Pr on Pr.id_ =L. project_id_
Where A.isfavoris_ =true and Pr.status_ in("Closed", "Archived","Suspended");
```

Then, I copy the result and separate them by a comma then put them between the () in the following Query

```
update  timemanagement_Assignment 
set  timemanagement_Assignment.isFavoris_=false
where id_  in ();
```

When I try to execute this in one step using :

```
 update  timemanagement_Assignment 
    set  timemanagement_Assignment.isFavoris_=false
    where id_  in (Select A.id_ from
    timemanagement_Assignment as A
    Left join project_Task as T on T.id_ =A.task_id_
    Left join project_Phase as P on P.id_ =T. phase_id_
    Left join project_Iteration as I on I.id_ =P. iteration_id_
    Left join project_Lot as L on L.id_ =I. Lot_id_
    Left join project_Project as Pr on Pr.id_ =L. project_id_
    Where A.isfavoris_ =true and Pr.status_ in("Closed", "Archived","Suspended"));
```

I got the following error `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'timemanagement_Assignment' for update in FROM clause`
I discovered that for some reason MySQL doesn't allow this type of queries.
Could you please help me to find a way to re-write this in one step to put it in an event ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure about those left joins?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure, I have been using this for a while an it work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps multi table update is what you need https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
update  timemanagement_Assignment 
        Left join project_Task as T on T.id_ =A.task_id_
        Left join project_Phase as P on P.id_ =T. phase_id_
        Left join project_Iteration as I on I.id_ =P. iteration_id_
        Left join project_Lot as L on L.id_ =I. Lot_id_
        Left join project_Project as Pr on Pr.id_ =L. project_id_
set  timemanagement_Assignment.isFavoris_=false
Where A.isfavoris_ =true and Pr.status_ in("Closed", "Archived","Suspended"));
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much that works, but it seems like I have to set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to 0, do you think this could have an impact ?